# ng-cloak not working in firefox

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ngcloak

Now I am working on some subview with coup ng-show for couple div, it works fine in chrome but not in FF.I searched online and did some tries, but none of them work for me, such as add .ng-cloak{display:none !important;}

```
  .state('accountsetting',
                {
                url:'/account',
                templateUrl:'settings/account.html'
                }
            )
  .state('accountsetting.personalcards',{
 url:'/personalcards',templateUrl:'submitter/PersonalCard/Personalcard.html'
                                        })
```

as you can see, in personalcards page, I define some divs  with ng-show
but in firefox everytime I go to this page,it will have flash(blink). it is very annoying, it works fine in chrome and IE. any idea?

Comment: If you are fetching data to show on Personalcards page, it could be you're seeing your template with no data to be shown yet.  ng-cloak won't fix that.  Can you show us the code for Personalcard html and the controller?

Comment: actually there is no data ,those ng-show divs are just some div with static content, I get confused why it only doesn't work in FF.

Comment: It's hard to say, can you show us the code for Personalcard.html?